# Updating manually with CPanel

Tags: 8, updating

I've updated my local site with composer.
Now I'm trying to update the production one:

1. Go to Cpanel.
2. On my local computer, take the local web folder and delete in it all 1-level files that are non-folders, and the sites folder.
3. Make a zip archive from the rest of the folders and upload it production (delete the invisible files too).
4. Delete on production all folders except the sites folder into trash.
5. Unzip the uploaded archive.
6. Change permissions for the uploaded folders:

> find /home/zb/public_html/core -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; find /home/zb/public_html/libraries -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; find /home/zb/public_html/modules -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; find /home/zb/public_html/profiles -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; find /home/zb/public_html/themes -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; find /home/zb/public_html/vendor -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

7. Reload the production site and it says that it encountered an unexpected error.

I've looked at error_log file and saw this:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: "Field uses_legacy_adjustments is unknown." at /home/zb/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php line 829

What do I do wrong? How to make the site work?

Comment: looks like you havent updated the database as the error is complaining about a missing file

Answer (score 0):

I should've compressed the updated index.php file and extracted it into the root directory as well and changed permissions of that file to 644. 
After I had done that the error disappeared and the site started working fine.
Then I updated the database.